# Combinatorics and probability exercise

Tags: combinatorics

The exercise is as follows: Group of $2N$ boys and $2N$ girls divided randomly into two equal groups. Calculate the probability that each group has the same quantity of girls and boys . Here is my solution to the problem.Did I get it right?

> $\frac{\binom{2N}{N}^2}{\binom{4N}{2N}}$

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Comment: You are welcome. Enjoy.